# An Entity with identical table data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Before I elaborate the problem, I'm well aware the database isn't designed conventionally.  Sadly, I can't change this particular database due to how it is integrated, so I've got a potential solution but that won't be implemented for several months.  In the mean time I need to work around the following:

The problem is I need to build an Entity, this would represent our `Accounts`.  But the problem, our database implements the following structure:

- Invoiced Table
- Non-Invoiced Table

My Entity, represents the exact same data on those tables, same column names, duplicate under all conditions, except one is invoiced while the other represents non-invoiced customers.  But since it isn't one table, with a Flag to indicate invoiced versus non-invoiced, how can my Entity link to both of those tables?

Since both tables represent separate names, I can't use the `[Table("...")]` or the auto mapping capabilities.  I hate asking such a question, but I can't find any documentation on how to handle such an issue.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but just out of curiosity, do both of those tables have the same columns?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes they do.  Which makes it even more absurd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use table-per-concrete class inheritance then define the table names on the derived types:

```
public abstract class Account
{
    // common entity code here
    ...
}

public class InvoicedAccount : Account {}
public class NonInvoicedAccount: Account {}

public YourContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<InvoicedAccount> InvoicedAccounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NonInvoicedAccount> NonInvoicedAccounts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<InvoicedAccounts>().Map( m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable( "InvoicedAccountTable" );
        } );

        modelBuilder.Entity<NonInvoicedAccounts>().Map( m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable( "NonInvoicedAccountTable" );
        } );
    }
}
```